# Loose focus of current control when press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have done some coding on blur event. SO I want to loose focus of current text box whenever enter event is call. This is what I have done so far. None of them are helping me out.

Requirement: My purpose is just to loose focus from current text box so it can fire is blur event.

Or

Redirecting focus to any other text box which dont requires `blur` event will be good for me

Try 1:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("input").trigger({
                type: 'keypress',
                which: 9
            });
            $("#Save").click();
        }
    });
    });
```

Try 2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).next().focus();
                $("#Save").click();
            }
        });
        });
```

Try 3:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.keyCode == 9;
                $("#Save").click();
            }
        });
    });
```

Try 4:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('input[type=text]:enabled:first').focus();
            $("#Save").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Try 5:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(document.activeElement) + 1);
                if (nextInput) {
                    nextInput.focus();
                }
                $("#Save").click();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the events to the input elements to what to do. Simulating a tabpress is kinda going here and there. Here is something, you can play around with

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type=text]').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 13) {
      var nextItem = $(this).next('input[type=text]');
      if( nextItem.size() === 0 ) {
        nextItem = $('input[type=text]').eq(0);
      }
      nextItem.focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=text /> <input type=text /> <input type=text />

<input type=button value=Save id="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use to focus the button itself and then click it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#Save").focus().click();
    }
  }).blur(function(e){
     alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
<br>
<input type='text' />
<br>
<button id='Save'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#save").focus().trigger("click");
    }
});
$("#save").click(function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"></input>
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    }
});
```

or trigger the blur event on itself.